# Vectorización de bucles en python

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

Poseo el siguiente codigo en Python:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
colum1 = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12]
colum2 = [10,20,30,40,50,60,70,80,90,100,110,120]

df = pd.DataFrame({
    'colum1' : colum1,
    'colum2' : colum2
});

df.loc[df.colum1 == 1,'result'] = df['colum2']

for i in range(len(colum2)):
    df.result = np.where(df.colum1>1, 5 - (df['colum2'] - df.result.shift(1)), df.result)
```

el resultado de df.result es:

```
    colum1  colum2  result
0        1      10    10.0
1        2      20    -5.0
2        3      30   -30.0
3        4      40   -65.0
4        5      50  -110.0
5        6      60  -165.0
6        7      70  -230.0
7        8      80  -305.0
8        9      90  -390.0
9       10     100  -485.0
10      11     110  -590.0
11      12     120  -705.0
```

Quisiera saber si existe algun metodo que me permita optener el mismo resultado sin necesidad de utilizar un ciclo for

Answer (score 1):

Es posible combinando [`apply()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html#pandas-dataframe-apply) y una variable global, francamente no creo que ganes mucho en claridad de código pero al menos responde a tu pregunta:

```
shift = None
def f(x):
  global shift
  ret = x if shift is None else 5 - (x - shift)
  shift = ret
  return ret

df['result2'] = df['colum2'].apply(f)
```

Lo que en tu código original sería `df.result.shift(1)` que termina funcionando como el valor `result` de la fila anterior que estamos acumulando, lo resolvemos con una variable global que va llevando el valor anterior de cada iteración.